# What is a Samurai bond?

Tags: investing, bonds

I saw this term "Samurai Bond" while I was reading about investing and bonds, but I am not sure about what this is. Can you please explain?

Comment: Fascinating - I'll admit this is the first time I've heard of it.  That's a cool name for a financial product.  Must be some exotic type of Japanese bond?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Samurai Bond is issued in Japan, in Yen, by a non-Japanese company, basically to distinguish between it from regular Japanese bonds.

The [investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/samuraibond.asp) has good details on this and many other topics.

There are similarly *funny* names for many other bond types, issued by *foreign* companies; and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bond_%28finance%29#Bonds_issued_in_foreign_currencies) has a listing.  Bulldog, Maple and Yankee are three common ones.

Comment: There are ninja bonds too, but you never know about them until it is way to late.

Comment: @MrChrister: Funny! :)))