# What's the difference between Currencies and FX desks at investment banks?

Tags: banking, currency, foreign-exchange, career, fixed-income

I'm interested in working within FX in an investment bank, but I noticed that they listed Currencies and FX separately under Fixed Income, so I'm wondering if they actually refer to different things. Can someone who has knowledge of this shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Can you point to this differentiation on the web somewhere?  Seems very odd.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the exact difference because I don't know which bank you are referring to. But FX typically deals with the [spot exchange rate](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/spotexchangerate.asp#axzz1b4OsLdf9) which is delivery of a particular currency (with respect to another currency) usually 2 days from the time of entering the contract. This is the kind of transactions that currency day traders speculate on. And also what the exchange rate you pay when you travel abroad is based on (usually calculated daily by local banking authorities).

Currency futures are contracts that calculate the future value of a particular currency at a longer period usually consisting of an exchange rate with respect to the US Dollar. These are typically used to hedge future cash flows by "locking in" an exchange rate similar to how other futures contracts operate.

Comment: So I'd just like to point out how immature and lame it is to downvote someone and note give explanation...

Answer (score 1):

**FX** is an abbreviation for `foreign exchange`. Sometimes you'll also see it referred to as **forex**.

It refers to transactions involving various currencies, and that is why it is called "foreign" exchange, because a currency conversion rate is always "foreign" from at least one party's point of view.

Foreign Exchange or Currencies are

- part of an investment bank's treasury, for cash management functions or perhaps proprietary trading, or
- the futures and options trading desk, for buy or sell side trading.

I can't imagine why both FX and Currencies would be listed as separate departments under Fixed Income. **Fixed income** refers specifically to bonds. Of course, bonds can be denominated such that there is foreign exchange exposure, see [What is a Samurai bond?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/what-is-a-samurai-bond) But there should be a Currencies or Foreign Exchange area that is uniquely separate as a department. **That** is where you would want to be if you wanted to be a currency trader.

Currency (or FX, or Forex) traders do not work on the Bond desk.

Comment: You will be surprised to see load of other instruments other than bonds classified under fixed income. CDOs and CDs for example.

Comment: FX/currencies are often grouped together with fixed income (e.g. [Macquarie](http://www.macquarie.com/us/aboutus/careers/graduates/our_business/tcg.htm)).

Comment: @DumbCoder Collateralized debt obligations are derivatives, or rather, structured products. So I would expect to see them on a Derivatives-type trading desk. Although there isn't much market for CDO's right now, and they aren't exchange traded with volume. Credit default swaps, well, yes, you have a point there. Are you certain they trade on the bond desk, not derivatives though?

Comment: @sheegaon In Macquarie's FICC division, services for sales, trading etc. are offered in 3 distinct categories: " **Fixed income–interest rate, debt and credit securities**, **Currency–FX spot, forward and tailored services** and **Commodities–metals...and related futures** " The FICC page and attached PDF describe staff as having "an underlying specialization in interest rate, commodity **OR** foreign exchange."

Comment: Agreed.  There are, of course, different people specializing in the different areas.  I'm just pointing out why the OP might be confused.

Comment: @sheegaon con't Job openings are "for interns in these **divisions** : **Securitized Debt Trading** or **Commodities Sales** " So different divisions and different jobs categories for FX versus bonds/ credit (maybe including credit derivatives) versus commodities. Macquarie PDF https://www.macquarie.com/about_macquarie/careers/FICCSummerInternshipOpportunities.pdf

Comment: @sheegaon So why doesn't my answer get up voted, as I actually respond directly to the OP's question? That was exactly what he asked about. He wanted guidance in sorting out which area of an investment bank he would work if he wanted to do FX. The other answer got up voted but didn't respond to the OP's question. I sound like I'm whining and grumpy. **Sorry.** This isn't **your**  fault. Actually, you were **great** cause you gave an example for me to work with, the Macquarie webpage and job openings. I wish I thought of that as a talking point to use when answering the actual question!

Comment: Personally, I have not up-voted anything here (question or answers) yet because I am waiting for a response to my comment on the question.  Can't speak for others.

Comment: Also, at my firm (buy-side, not I-Bank), FX traders sit right next to the bond traders because the markets are considered closely linked, so there is a bit of inaccuracy in your answer.

Comment: @sheegaon Ooh! I didn't see that. Very good idea. I wasn't accusing you of anything. Like I said, you actually provided a relevant example from an investment bank website, which was the perfect thing to do. I'm not grumping at you at all. Really! **;@)** <--- Happy Piggy smile from Feral Oink.

Comment: @sheegaon Unless one works in spacious quarters, trading desks DO have a tendency to be jammed together, nearly elbow to elbow. And there is exchange of ideas and cross-consulting. That's why I mentioned foreign currency denominated bonds, Samurais weren't even the best example. You're correct, because in that sense, and many more, there can be overlap.